# Angular 2 custom validation not calling inside of component function

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to find the duplicate dealer name with custom validators. The dealers name data comes from web-service. I have dealer service to get the dealer data. And I am using it for dealer duplicate validation at validDelarName function inside component. And I am declaring it on FromGroup Validators but it's not being called.

```
Form Group Validator - declare

name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(128),Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9\\s\\-\\,\\.\\&\\(\\)]+'),(control:FormControl)=>this.validDelarName])],
```

Validation function. It's also present in component.

```
 validDelarName(FormControl){   
  const dealer = this.dealer.getviewdealer().subscribe( //getting data using webservices
  (data) => {       
     data.forEach(items => {
      for (var key in items) {
        if (items.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

          if(control.value == items['dealername']){
            return {valid:true;}
          }
          else{
            retrun null;
          }

        }
      }
     });
  }

);
 }
```

Comment: I have post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there are a lot of mistakes in your code, let's enumerate it:

1 - Since your custom validator `validDelarName` is `async`, it **must** go as the 3rd. parameter, like this:

```
name: [
  '', 
  [
    Validators.required, 
    Validators.maxLength(128),
    Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9\\s\\-\\,\\.\\&\\(\\)]+')
  ],
  (control: AbstractControl) => this.validDelarName // Fix later
]
```

2 - You have to pass the control or the *context* to your custom validator, like below:

```
(control: AbstractControl) => this.validDelarName(control)
```

or if you prefer:

```
this.validDelarName.bind(this)
```

3 - The `validDelarName`'s signature is wrong, it must be like this:

```
validDelarName(control: AbstractControl) { ... }
```

4 - The `async` *validator* waits or a `Promise` or an `Observable` and you're returning only `null | errorObj` inside the `forEach`, which one isn't doing anything.

**Solution:**

Instead of `subscribe` you could use `map` operator (or if you want you can use a Promise) and let Angular do his job.

To search for a specific value in your `array` I'd suggest you to use [**Array#some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example). It'll returns true if it finds the typed text in the array and will automatically stop the loop, otherwise it'll return false.

Based on this, you can return the *error* `object` or null, like this:

```
validDelarName(control: AbstractControl) {
  return this.dealer.getviewdealer().map(data => {
    const hasItem: boolean = data.some(item => control.value === item['dealername']);

    return hasItem ? { valid: true } : null;
  });
}
```

5 - As you can see above, you don't need to iterate over all the keys of `data` *object* (as you're doing) since you only want to compare the `dealername`.

6 (Minor mistake) - You have a typo in `retrun null;`, should be `return null;` :).

7 (Credits to @yurzui) - `return {valid:true;} should be return { valid: true };`

---

**Tips:**

1 - The `Validators.compose` isn't needed, you can just pass an `array`, or if it's a single validator, the validator itself, in both parameters (2nd and 3rd).

2 - [**`Validators.pattern`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern) accepts a `RegExp`, so you can use it.

Why? Instead of escaping the symbols with double slashes, you can escape only a single slash and IMO, it's more readable.

*Sample*:

```
Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s-\,\.&\(\)]+$/)
```

Also, note that **not all** symbols here needs to be escaped (I take out the unneeded escaping).

[**FULL DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/vnD1B1uL1LwrOnFfkHJV?p=info)

Comment: Good answer! 7. `return {valid:true;}` should be `return {valid:true}` :)

Comment: @yurzui Oh, I missed that one. I just added it, thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks, @developer033. It's really worked for me. You described it step by step. That thing is really helped me to understand very easily. Actually, I am beginner level in angular2. Once again thanks for your great answer and you too yurzi.